# How to take dynamic value of Examples to run for Scenario_Outline in behave

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

```
Feature: showing off behave style

Scenario Outline: wow
    Given I put "<brand_one/brand_two>" in a blender
    When we implement a test

    Examples: Brand
        | brand_one|brand_two|
        | first Frog | second Frog|
```

I want to select brand_one or brand_two at run time.
On executing feature file i just want to execute method taking value of brand_one (i.e first Frog) or brand_two (i.e seconf Frog) at run time. But only execute one desired brand and not the other one. Please help me out to select this on run time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use tags for this:

```
Feature: showing off behave style

Scenario Outline: wow
    Given I put "<brand>" in a blender
    When we implement a test

    @FrogOne
    Examples: Brand
        | brand|
        | first Frog |   

    @FrogTwo
    Examples: Brand
        | brand|
        | second Frog|
```

Then choose it at run time like so

```
behave -t FrogOne
```

or

```
behave --tags FrogOne
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can pass --tags? I dont want to pass -t in command.
I am having configuration file from which i can get whether run for FrogOne or FrogTwo.
so can we use that configuration file variable, it will be having one value (i.e FrogOne or FrogTwo at a time)
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yes, you can do --tags instead of -t 

Comment: No i dont want to pass -t or --tags. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of this configuration file?

Comment: it is simply a file with a variable named "brand=FrogOne" in it and is imported in environment.py

Comment: I have tried updating behave.ini file in before_all by using file operations of python but its still not working as expected. Please help me on this.